# Find the next point. Simple gift-wrapping algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, convex-hull

#### Hi

I was reading the [gift-wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) on Wikipedia and felt like I understood it moderately well (I was wrong). Because of this I thought I should try too implement it in python. However the Pseudo-code on Wikipedia loses me at several points.

```
1:jarvis(S)
2:   pointOnHull = leftmost point in S
3:   i = 0
4:   repeat
5:      P[i] = pointOnHull
6:      endpoint = S[0]         // initial endpoint for a candidate edge on the hull
7:      for j from 1 to |S|
8:         if (endpoint == pointOnHull) or (S[j] is on left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
9:            endpoint = S[j]   // found greater left turn, update endpoint
10:      i = i+1
11:      pointOnHull = endpoint
12:   until endpoint == P[0]      // wrapped around to first hull point
```

Presuming I'm working with a list of coords I.E

```
[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]
```

I understand how to get pointOnHull and i understand that the outer loop is looping for each item on the hull while the inner loop is all points in the set of points. However i don't really understand what is going on inside the for loop and I don't understand how

```
(S[j] is on the left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
```

Is calculated?
Surely it is calculable from a list of coordinates but i just cant see how.
A slightly more verbose explanation would help me very much, or perhaps just a different explanation.

Comment: Maybe look at http://tomswitzer.net/2009/12/jarvis-march/

Comment: @DavidGreydanus " in CCW order" This looks very helpful, thank you.